# Blinear Interpolation Returns Repeating Blocky Image

Tags: c#, interpolation, unity-game-engine

So, I was trying to come up with my own simple implementation of Perlin/Fractal noise(I'm just adding the noise to itself resampled multiple times).

When it comes to the resampling part of the algorithm, to achieve lower frequency noise I'm using bilinear interpolation on a smaller part of the array to effectively "stretch out" that smaller part (i.e: look at a 16x16 part of a 256x256 sheet of noise, but treat it as if it was a 256x256 array of pixels)

The site I use (well, one of them) for reference is http: //lodev.org/cgtutor/randomnoise.html

From the site the first two pictures is the result I'm looking for but instead i get something like this (I used a 64x64 array):

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YIcW.png)

[Resampled using x8 Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTZaI.png)

All of the code I'm using is in Unity (I know there is a built-in Perlin-generator for it, but I wanted my own):

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class NoiseGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

```
//Dimensions of the array
public int width;
public int height;

//RNG Stuff for reproducability
public bool useTimeAsSeed;
public string seed;

//The array the nopise gets stored in
int[,] noise;

//These are used in the editor to control if we zoon in or not, original image gets resized to 1/ratio
public bool zoom;
public int ratio=1;


//Function used to fill up the array with white noise (random numbers with a uniform distribution between 0-255)
void InitNoise() {
    noise = new int[width, height];
    if (useTimeAsSeed) {
        seed = Time.time.ToString();
    }
    System.Random r = new System.Random(seed.GetHashCode());
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            noise[x, y] = r.Next(0,256);                
        }
    }       
}


//Function to smooth the noise when it's being resampled
/*
    AB
    CD
    |when resampled
    v
    A--R---B
    |  X   | 
    |      |
    |      |
    C--J---D

    Uses bilinear Interpolation to get the wighted average of A B C and D, which are all neighbouring pixels in the original picture
    Returns an int value between 0-255
*/
int SmoothNoise(float x, float y) {
    float fractX = x - (int)x; //Fractional part of the X-coord, used as the weight for Lerping in the x-direction
    float fractY = y - (int)y; //Fractional part of the Y-coord, used as the weight for Lerping in the y-direction
    //Calculating the neigbouring pixels
    //For edge values the respective "missing pixel" is filled in by the other end of the noise sheet
    int x1 = ((int)x + width) % width;
    int x2 = (x1 + width - 1) % width;
    int y1 = ((int)y + height) % height;
    int y2 = (y1 + height - 1) % height;
    //Calculating R and J by Lerping the respective pixels
    float R = Mathf.Lerp(noise[x1, y1], noise[x2, y1], fractX);
    float J = Mathf.Lerp(noise[x2, y1], noise[x2, y2], fractX);
    //Finally Lerp R and J to get the value for X
    return (int)(Mathf.Lerp(R,J,fractY));
}

void Start() {
    InitNoise();        
}
//Easy way to display the array as a temporary solution until actual terrain display is implemented
void OnDrawGizmos() {
    if (noise != null) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
                float component = (float)noise[x, y] / 255;
                if (zoom) {
                    //Using the result of SmoothNoise normalised to be between 0-1 we construct a color component to be used when displaying
                    component = (float)SmoothNoise((float)x/ratio, (float)y/ratio) / 255;
                }                    
                Gizmos.color = new Color(component,component,component);
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3(-width/2 + x + .5f, 0, -height/2 + y + .5f);
                Gizmos.DrawCube(pos, Vector3.one);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is better to do this using Matlab.  You can always generate a Matlab dll that can be called from c#.

Comment: It should be float J = Mathf.Lerp(noise[x1, y2]... I think

Comment: Thanks for the rather quick replies(Unlike me). As it turns out @Antonín Lejsek was right, suspecting that I sampled the wrong coordinates, it's all fixed now so I'm happy :) I may replace the smoothing used by smoothstep at some point, but overall thanks for the help.